# Obtain NSURL from UIImagePickerController

Tags: swift, firebase, swift2, nsurl, firebase-realtime-database

I'm attempting to grab the file path of an image selected through an imagePickerController in order to upload the file to Firebase Storage.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    mediaUploadView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

    let localUrl: NSURL = (info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL)
    print(localUrl)

    let localFile: NSURL = localUrl
    let mediaRef = storageRef.child("media")

    let uploadTask = mediaRef.putFile(localUrl, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
        if (error != nil) {
        } else {
            let downloadURL = metadata!.downloadURL
        }
    }


    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

The output reads:

```
assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=C224DA06-6B7B-4BE2-8F5E-2EC7BC8B0526&ext=JPG
Body file is unreachable: /asset.JPG
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file doesn’t exist."
```

It grabs what I believe is the NSURL, but then is unable to find it for upload.

I have attempted to follow along with this similar problem on stack "[How do I get Image reference and upload image to Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516742/how-do-i-get-image-reference-and-upload-image-to-firebase)" but the output then simply returns nil. 
Any help would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had trouble getting the `info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]` to work. I had to do it like this:

```
let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs([localUrl], options: nil)
let asset = assets.firstObject
asset?.requestContentEditingInputWithOptions(nil, completionHandler: { (contentEditingInput, info) in
    let imageFile = contentEditingInput?.fullSizeImageURL
    // now call putFile with imageFile instead of localURL
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sharud! Took me a second to get it but its working now! I've been trying to get this for nearly 5 days so I can't even tell you how stoked I am. Again, thanks man! Huge help!!

Comment: Yay! Glad I could help. You got me to 50 reputation, so I can comment now :) So we helped each other out haha. Anyways, the initial `localURL` is a url to the Photos App assets. So then you need to fetch it as an asset url. Could never quite figure out why I had to request it with editing, but it was the only way I could get it to work.

Comment: Glad I could help you out too haha! I appreciate the explanation, I'm new to coding so a lot goes right over my head. The content editing does seem odd but as long as it gets the job done I'm happy! Have a good one man!